# Removing chunks of lines with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to go through a file and keep a consecutive group of `4` rows out of each consecutive group of `40` rows.

So in the whole file, I would keep rows `1-4`, `41-44`, `81-84`, etc.
I tried using `sed`, but I am really only able to remove specific rows, not do a pattern like this.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'NR%40==1 || NR%40==2 || NR%40==3 || NR%40==4' file
```

A loop version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<5;i++) if (NR%40==i) print $0}' file
```

Found this should work after I tested various solution:

```
awk 'NR%40~/^[1-4]$/' file
```

---

test

```
seq 1 100 > file
```

```
awk 'NR%40~/^[1-4]$/' file
1
2
3
4
41
42
43
44
81
82
83
84
```

Comment: @merlin2011 No, this prints 1,2,3,4,41,42,43 etc like OP request

Comment: @merlin2011 found an even shorter one after some testing

Comment: @Jotne, Very nice. :) I hope you will answer the next time *I* ask a question about how to shorten spaghetti `awk` code.

Comment: @merlin2011 Thanks.  I am sometime impressed my self on how short code that actually works.  I did lots of test to get this to work and its so nice that I add it to my personal `awk` list. I did try like this `NR%40==1|2` `NR%40=="1|2"` `NR%40==(1|2)` `NR%40==/1|2/` `NR%40==/[1-2]/` `NR%40~"1|2"` `NR%40~/1|2/` `NR%40~/[1-2]/` none working, then though about limiting the field using `^` and `$` and finally got this to work `NR%40~/^[1-2]$/` and now I see that `NR%40~/^(1|2|3|4)$/` also works :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '1~40,+3p' file
```

Use a 40 line step starting at line 1 and range it over 4 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with `awk`. This is **not the most concise solution**, but should get you what you want. The variable `NR` represents the row number.

```
 awk '(NR - 1) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 2) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 3) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 4) % 40 ==0 ' Input.txt
```

I tested this like this:

```
 seq 1 50 > /tmp/Input.txt
 awk '(NR - 1) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 2) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 3) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 4) % 40 ==0 ' /tmp/Input.txt
```

If you want to modify the original file, then output it to a temporary file and move it back.

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 2) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 3) % 40 ==0 || (NR - 4) % 40 ==0 ' Input.txt > /tmp/TempOutput
mv /tmp/TempOutput Input.txt
```

Comment: merline2011: Thanks! But for some reason, it does not seem to work for me. I have a file with the numbers 1 to 124 on each line, and when I run that command with my fileName at the end, and then cat the result, the file does not seem to change...

Comment: @user2808302, `awk` does not do in-place changes. You need to redirect the output to another file if you want the contents in a new file.

Comment: @merlin2011 `GNU awk` 4.1 or later can do in-place changes. Here is a [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace) to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

simple but do what is asked (thks to @Jotne for remark based on seq test)

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N' YourFile
```

just for fun

```
sed -n '
x    
s/^$/ppppfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff/
s/^p//
t keep
s/^f//
x
b
:keep
x
p' YourFile
```

there is another more traditionnal way by using only `d`, `p` and `N` but not funny at all :-).
I use a kind of template counter that `p`rint and `f`orget lines (the `ppppfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`) keep in hold buffer

Comment: You new `N;N` solution does not give correct result.  Try `seq 100 | sed 'N;N;N;p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d'` and you get `1
2
3
4
41
42
43
44
81
82
83
84
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100`

Comment: `iter=1;while [ $iter -lt 300 ]; do echo "$iter" ;let iter+=1; done | sed 'N;N;N;p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d'` give 
`1
2
3
4
41
42
43
44
81
82
83
84
121
122
123
124
161
162
163
164
201
202
203
204
241
242
243
244
281
282
283
284
` on my AIX/bash/sed

Comment: Your test does work correctly on my Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, but not the `seq 100 | sed ..` `-e` does not help.

Comment: just test on a linux and same strange behaviour as you mention. `seq` generate something different after line 80 but don't see difference. After 81, each line seems to be printed. Due to not finished cycle (print of last line before delete it). I adapt the script (using of sed -n)

Comment: Now it works as expected, and using 9.2 seconds on my test file, so its fast.