# Removing chunks of lines with sed: Needs an improved time

Tags: performance, awk, sed

This is an extension to my recent post ([Removing chunks of lines with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357556/removing-chunks-of-lines-with-sed)).

I already gave it the "check" but then I realized that it might not be so good for my actual file. My file is really big, and the solution that was provided to me prints as it goes, which is going to take too long. Does anyone know of a solution that will be *quick* for large files by maybe just removing lines instead of copying and pasting etc?

PROBLEM:

I am trying to go through a file and keep a consecutive group of 4 rows out of each consecutive group of 40 rows.

So in the whole file, I would keep rows 1-4, 41-44, 81-84, etc.
I tried using sed, but I am really only able to remove specific rows, not do a pattern like this.

THE PREVIOUS SOLUTIONS:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<5;i++) if (NR%40==i) print $0}' file
//That prints as it goes

awk 'NR%40~/^[1-4]$/' file
// This requires it to print to a new file by adding " > file2" at the end, which I think is slower than necessary.
```

Any better solutions to save time?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with the `time` command do see how ling it takes?  How big is the file?

Comment: Hi Jotne: The file is about 16G. I did not try the time, but it ran for about 30 minutes before I killed it. I am applying it to several files, so I am worried it will just add up! But as I don't know much about Linux commands etc., I don't know how much it can be improved upon. Is my thinking right, though, to say that printing it to a new file is slow? I just don't know if there are other alternatives.

Comment: The other thing is that I only tried the top line, not the bottom line, that I listed under "the previous solutions" above. I wonder if the bottom line would be faster? I just thought that also could be slow, though, as it is printing to a new file the whole time, right?

Comment: On a 1GB test text file the `awk 'NR%40~/^[1-4]$/'` used 1 min and 20 sec.  The `awk '{for (i=1;i<5;i++) if (NR%40==i) print $0}'` used 1 min and 26 sec (so loop does not need to mean much slower). The `sed` from Neron used 57 seconds.  So it will take time, not sure if you find any faster solution.

Comment: do you try my sed solution ? but sed will be slower than awk

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using sed, but I am really only able to remove specific rows,
>   not do a pattern like this.

You could, using GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1~40p;2~40p;3~40p;4~40p' filename
```

For example:

```
$ seq 100 | sed -n '1~40p;2~40p;3~40p;4~40p' 
1
2
3
4
41
42
43
44
81
82
83
84
```

Comment: @ A nice and fast solution.  On my 1GB test file it uses 13 seconds.

Comment: @Jotne See a better variant of this answer just posted by potong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23361589/2235132

Comment: Potongs solution 9 seconds on my test file, best so far.

Comment: @Jotne I could guess so without testing :)  Given that it just needs to look for 1/4th of the addresses.